# Intermittent unit-test failure associated with i18next

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, i18next, aurelia

I am trying to unit test my aurelia custom element, which looks like below.

```
// BaseText.ts
import { bindable } from "aurelia-framework";
import { BaseI18N } from "aurelia-i18n";

export class BaseText extends BaseI18N {
    @bindable public value: string;
    @bindable public i18nKey: string;
}

// NormalText.ts
export class NormalTextCustomElement extends BaseText {}

// NormalText.html
<template>
    <span t.bind="i18nKey">${value}</span>
</template>
```

Now, I want to test if I change the value of `i18nKey`, the translated text is shown in the element. To test that, I have written the below test case.

```
describe("i18n specs", () => {

    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
        component = StageComponent
            .withResources("NormalText/NormalText")
            .inView("<normal-text id='i18n1' value='Ignored Text' i18n-key='test'></normal-text>");

        component.bootstrap((aurelia: Aurelia) => aurelia.use
            .standardConfiguration()
            .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName("aurelia-i18n"), (instance) => {
                const aliases = ["t"];
                TCustomAttribute.configureAliases(aliases);

                return instance.setup({
                    attributes: aliases,
                    fallbackLng: "en",
                    lng: "en",
                    resources: {         //<-- translation resources
                        en: {
                            translation: {
                                test: "English test"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }));

    });

    it("Should render the translated text with a i18nKey", (done) => {
        component
            .create(bootstrap)
            .then(() => {
                const spanElement = document.querySelector('normal-text#i18n1>span');
                expect(spanElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('English test');
            })
            .catch(e => { console.log(e.toString()) })
            .finally(() => {
                component.dispose();
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Now the problem is that this test case fails intermittently, which surely is going to be a problem with CI. I suspect that it has something to do it the initialization of i18next, and the test case is running before the initialization is complete. Though I am not very sure about this hypothesis.

What should I change, so that this test case becomes deterministic?

**Additional info:**

1. This test case succeeds if it runs before every other [view related test cases](https://github.com/Sayan751/test-au-plugin/blob/master/tests/NormalText/NormalText.spec.ts#L33-L121).
2. I have created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Sayan751/test-au-plugin), so that interested reader/user can reproduce the problem. Please keep in mind that you might have run the tests multiple times to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out that the issue is actually related to how I was writing the test cases.

Previously I had structured it as below.

```
describe("View specs", ()=> {
  // here goes other test suite and/or test cases
  describe("i18n specs", () => {

    let component;
    beforeEach(() => {
      // here goes the custom initialization code of aurelia, as shown in question
    });
  });
});
```

I think this custom initialization code was interfering with the other test cases with default bootstrapping. I simply pulled out the `beforeEach` from the `i18n specs` and put it directly under the `View specs` test suite. Which means that all of the test cases under `View specs` test suite are using same aurelia bootstrapping setup. And actually that did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you're right. Init call of i18next is async. Means it won't be finished before test run.

You do not want to test the translations itself - so setting language to "cimode" for test cases will result in consistent return of the key instead of the translation value.

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I understand that using `cimode` makes the testing easier, as I don't have to explicitly specify any translation resources. However, the problem of initializing i18next before the running test cases still remains.

Comment: should not hurt. the init call will be done - but results of translations are based on cimode always key - init done or not. If still to fast -> cimode not set before running tests use -> https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options#initimmediate and eventual add an empty resources: {} on init so it does not load any translations via xhr

Comment: I have found a simpler solution to my problem. I posted it as the answer. However, your answer provided few useful tools for easier testing. Thank you for that :)